# ReactJS: this is reserved word

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass styling data via the `style` prop from a Parent component to the Child component, however I am getting the following error:

> this is reserved word

Here is the relevant code relating to my problem:

**Child:**

```
render {

    return (<table>
    <tr style={{backgroundColor: {this.props.color}}}> ...some text here...</tr>
    </table>)
}
```

**Parent:**

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
       color: "red"  
    }
}

render() {
    return <Child color={this.state.color} />
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a small syntax error in the `render()` method of your Child component.

Removing the `{` and `}` around `this.props.color` will resolve the issue:

```
<tr style={{backgroundColor: this.props.color}}> ...some text here...</tr>
```